# How to upgrade the repositories locations from focal to jammy? (apt update)

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, repository

Through VirtualBox was installed long time ago Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 (`focal`)  and was upgraded successfully to 22.04 `jammy`

Now, the reason of this post, when the `sudo apt update` command is executed appears:

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                       
Hit:3 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                        
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                     
Hit:5 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                            
Hit:6 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
11 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

Observe the two first lines, they contain the `focal` term, and the others lines contain the `jammy` term.

How to upgrade the repositories locations from `focal` to `jammy`?

The goal is update correctly MySQL and Docker.

Comment: I suggest using ppa-purge to remove all software installed from those sources as well as the sources themselves. Then re-add the ppas if you still need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `Software & Sources`, and go to the `Other Software` Tab.

Find the repository corresponding to MySQL and Docker, and click on `Edit`.

Afterwards, change `focal` to `jammy`. Run `sudo apt update`.

---

Beware that the repositories may not host packages for `jammy` (in that case, `sudo apt update` will show warnings, and if that happens it would be a good idea to remove those repositories).

---

In Ubuntu Server, you can find the software sources (text files) in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. Edit them, and replace focal with jammy.

(This method also works in Ubuntu Desktop)

Comment: Thanks, and how to accomplish the same goal but for server environment? of course if this case happens

Comment: @ManuelJordan I have updated the answer for Ubuntu Server

Comment: Hello could you consider the following situation? It is a consequence about your answer - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1497140/how-to-fix-apt-update-after-to-upgrade-the-mysql-list-file